# MongoDB (v3.2.4) Fluent - Aggregate group sum is always 0

Tags: c#, mongodb, fluent

I'm trying to filter on millions of documents inside a collection, then applying a grouping on one of the properties. I need to know the sum of the amount properties. I've written the following code already, but the sum seems to be 0 always, even though the amount exists within each document in the collection.

```
var results = collection.Aggregate().Match(expression)
            .Project(data => new
            {
                Id = data.Id,
                Name = data.Name,
                Amount = data.NetAmount
            })
            .Group(
                key => new { key.Id, key.Name },
                grouping => new
                {
                    IdAndName = grouping.Key,
                    GroupTotalAmount = grouping.Sum(obj => obj.Amount)
                })
            .Project(arg => new
            {
                Id = arg.IdAndName.Id,
                Name = arg.IdAndName.Name,
                Amount = arg.GroupTotalAmount
            });
```

If I use `1` instead of `obj.Amount`, in the above code snippet, I get the counts for the grouped collection.

Moreover, if I just project without group in the pipeline, I can see the `Amount` value populated for each document.

This is my `expression` in the above code:

```
Expression<Func<MyObject, bool>> expression = data => data.PropertyA == 55 && data.PropertyB == 2000;
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please update post with some sample documents and minimum verifiable code.

Comment: Odds are that your "Amount" data is actually a "string" and therefore cannot be "numerically" summed. You would need to change the data so that things that "should" be numeric actually are.

Comment: @NeilLunn - The Amount is of decimal type, the net amount in the document is of decimal as well.

Comment: I'll believe it when I see it. A `0` as a result of `$sum` is generally an indicator of non-numeric data somewhere in the dataset. It's all very well to "tell" us that is what you have, but it's useless to solving your problem until you **show** us. [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36574823/edit) your question to include stored document details as requested, and check your collection to see that **all** data in the `NetAmount` property is in fact numeric. Include your MongoDB server version, since that is also of relevance.

Comment: @NeilLunn I actually figured it out, you were right, the type was causing an issue. I used decimal type on the C# side, but the documents were storing it as a string. I'm currently updating the types for the amounts in the documents using a JavaScript shell command. Wonder why MongoDB was not supporting decimal C# types.

Comment: Of course I was right, Proper serialization types are well documented.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your input.